# Python If Statement - Ignore lines if row value from mysql is 0

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am very new at Python.
I want make an `MySQL query` if the row value is not `0`. If its `0` i want ignore the following lines in my loop.

**Code:**

```
if MYVALUE is not 0:

    getvalue = db.cursor()
    query = ("SELECT member_id " +
               "FROM user "
               "WHERE number = %s ")
    numbervalue = (MYVALUE,)
    getvalue.execute(query, numbervalue)
    getvalueid_row = getvalue.fetchone()
    result = getvalueid_row[0]

    time.sleep(LOOP_SECONDS)
```

Sometimes `MYVALUE = 0` and sometimes an random number like: `MYVALUE = 43012578547`

But `if MYVALUE is not 0:` dont work and the code after, it runs also if `MYVALUE = 0`:
and then i get an row `None` error:

How can i solve it?

Comment: FWIW You should use `!=` with numbers, not `is not`

Comment: Are you making sure that ``MYVALUE`` is an ``int``? Maybe it's the string ``"0"``, in which case it's only natural that the block will be executed.

Comment: You mean `if MYVALUE != 0:`

Comment: what you mean with `int` ? sorry its the first time i work with python;) `MYVALUE = account_row[6]`

Comment: If you do not know the difference between a string and an integer, you should work through some tutorials first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be like:

If value is 0 i.e. int:

```
if MYVALUE != 0:
    getvalue = db.cursor()
    query = ("SELECT member_id " +
           "FROM user "
           "WHERE number = %s ")
    numbervalue = (MYVALUE,)
    getvalue.execute(query, numbervalue)
    getvalueid_row = getvalue.fetchone()
    result = getvalueid_row[0]

    time.sleep(LOOP_SECONDS)
```

If value is "0" i.e. string:

```
if MYVALUE != "0":
    getvalue = db.cursor()
    query = ("SELECT member_id " +
           "FROM user "
           "WHERE number = %s ")
    numbervalue = (MYVALUE,)
    getvalue.execute(query, numbervalue)
    getvalueid_row = getvalue.fetchone()
    result = getvalueid_row[0]

    time.sleep(LOOP_SECONDS)
```

Comment: It comes the error: `TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'` now, any ideas why?

Comment: `result = getvalueid_row[0]`

Comment: Check whether you are getting query output

Comment: As i say above If value is not `0` it works fine all, but if row in MySQL is "0" value it comes this error, thats why i want ignore all with `if MYVALUE != 0:` if row DB value is `0` and not an number. But it seems like `if MYVALUE != 0` dont ignore the lines after it.

Comment: Yes output is `MYVALUE:0` if i enable logging

Comment: I guess 0 is coming in string format. Please check the above edited code

Comment: You mean if `MYVALUE` result is in string format? like `if str(REF_COMFR != 0):`? My loggin line is in string = `str(MYVALUE)`

Comment: Tell me datatype of ```MYVALUE``` by using ```print(type(MYVALUE))```

Comment: Please try one of the solution updated by me above and let me know if any of those works

Comment: Yes i try it at the moment and tell you, thanks for your help:)

Comment: The 2nd solution will work. I am guessing that ```if MYVALUE != "0":```` will work

Comment: Yes it was an `string` and second one works fine, many thanks for your time:)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `!=` operator:

```
if MYVALUE != 0:
    # code...
```

Comment: `TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'` error comes now.